# How to fix out-of-order sequence number with existing GTID error

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-replication, mysqlbinlog, gtid

I am attaching a database to a master and after a while, I get the following error when I run `show slave status`, I get the following error:

> An attempt was made to binlog GTID 1-XXX-XXXXXXXXX which would create an out-of-order sequence number with existing GTID 1-YYY-YYYYYYYYY, and gtid strict mode is enabled.

I would appreciate not just steps on how to fix it, but perhaps an explanation of why this error is happening in the first place.

Thanks!

Comment: I have quite the same issue, did you find a solution for that? I couldn't do anything except setting up the replication again from a backup

Comment: This is probably more suited to [dba.se]. See also this question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/189844/sql-slave-skip-counter-1-fails-setting-gtid-slave-pos-used-to-skip-a-given